# ESP8266 refuses connection to Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: javascript, http, arduino, raspberry-pi, esp8266

i'm building a weather station and trying to write to my database with my NodeMCU ESP8266. Therefore i connect to a Node.js Server and my API does the database stuff. When i run the server code on my windows machine it just works fine. I installed everything on a Raspberry Pi Zero W and when i test it with a browser or Postman it still works...but unfortunately my ESP refuses to establish a connection now. Does anybody know the reason for this?

Code of Arduino:

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <Adafruit_BMP085.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Wire.h>

//declare
Adafruit_BMP085 bmp;
HTTPClient http;
StaticJsonBuffer<256> jsonBuffer;
JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.createObject();

char ssid[] = //SSID;
char key[] = //PASSWORD;


//declare variables
float temperature = 0.0;
float pressure = 0.0;
float pressureSea = 0.0;
float rssi = 0.0;
String mac = "00:00:00:00:00:00";
char payload[256];

void setup() {
// --------------- WIFI Configuration --------------
    Serial.begin(115200);
    while (!Serial);
    Serial.println();

    WiFi.begin(ssid, key);

    Serial.print("Connecting");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println();

    Serial.print("Connected, IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

// ---------------- Sensor Config --------------------

    Wire.pins(5, 4);
    Wire.begin(5, 4);

    if (!bmp.begin()) {
        Serial.println("No BMP180 / BMP085");// we dont wait for this
        while (1) {}
      }
    }

void loop() {

    measure();
    sendData();

    Serial.print("Temperatur: ");
    Serial.print(temperature);
    Serial.println(" °C");

    Serial.print("Druck: ");
    Serial.print(pressure);
    Serial.println(" hPa");

    Serial.print("RSSI: ");
    Serial.println(rssi);
    Serial.print("MAC: ");
    Serial.println(mac);


    Serial.println();

    delay(10000);
}

void measure () {

    // Environment Measure
    temperature = bmp.readTemperature();
    pressure = bmp.readPressure() / 100;

    // Signal Measure
    rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
    mac = WiFi.macAddress();

}

void sendData () {

    root["temp"] = temperature;
    root["press"] = pressure;
    root["rssi"] = rssi;
    root.printTo(payload, sizeof(payload));

    Serial.println(payload);

    http.begin("http://192.168.87.76:3000/api/weather");
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    int httpCode = http.POST(payload);
    //http.writeToStream(&Serial);
    http.end();

    Serial.println(httpCode);
    if (httpCode < 0) {
    Serial.printf("Request failed: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());}

    Serial.println();
}
```

Node.js-Server:

```
// SERVER SETUP

// Get dependencies
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors')

// Get our API routes
const api = require('./server/routes/api');

const app = express();

//Enable CORS
app.use(cors());

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);


/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
app.listen(port,'0.0.0.0');
```

Output of HTTP-Client Debugger:

```
[HTTP-Client][begin] url: http://192.168.87.51:3000/api/weather
[HTTP-Client][begin] host: 192.168.87.51 port: 3000 url: /api/weather
Status: 0
[HTTP-Client] failed connect to 192.168.87.51:3000
[HTTP-Client][returnError] error(-1): connection refused
[HTTP-Client][end] tcp is closed
-1
Request failed: connection refused
```

Netstat on Pi:

```
sudo netstat -tulpen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          11766      466/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       12846      590/node
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      109        10991      354/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          11773      466/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      109        10992      354/postgres
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           108        10184      238/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           0          10888      450/dhcpcd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48824           0.0.0.0:*                           108        10186      238/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                108        10185      238/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::34435                :::*                                108        10187      238/avahi-daemon: r
```

If you have a clue or any tips i apprechiate it very much! Thank you!

Comment: try using GET instead of POST; it's easy to build URL. modify the httpClient example to get started

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I got it working now. The programming was fine but the pi didn‘t replied to the ARP request from the ESP. Don‘t know why but ARP Proxy in the router does the job!